# Closing duplicates between StackOverflow and Facebook.StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

This question:

- [Where to store an image, if want to post an it on the wall/page of facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347545/where-to-store-an-image-if-want-to-post-an-it-on-the-wall-page-of-facebook)

was posted on stackoverflow.com at 11h47'44Z today.

This question:

- [what is location of image?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7347585/what-is-location-of-image)

was posted on facebook.stackoverflow.com at 11h50'56Z, today also.

The asker is the same user, and the text is virtually identical.

Trying to close this second one as a duplicate of the first returns:

> The duplicate question must exist on Facebook - Stack Overflow

(Same thing happens while trying to close the other way around, minus the Facebook.)

Is this interesting little double-posting "feature" intentional? Should such duplicates be flagged for moderator attention or is there something else that can be done in such cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They both have facebook tags, and both exist on facebook.SO.  You just needed to edit the URL so that they both have the subdomain, i.e. add `facebook` to the beginning of the SO one.

I flagged to close [7347545](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7347545) as a dupe of [7347585](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7347585) since the latter has an answer.  It is now closed :)

Comment: Ah! Hadn't thought about prepending `facebook.` to the first. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you just use the numeric question ID, or make sure the dupe URL has the same domain as the site you're closing on, it works. After all the questions are identical, whether the domain starts with "facebook." or not.

We should probably make sure it works anyway, but there's your workaround until then.

Comment: Not sure adding a feature to handle it automatically is worth it. I feel kind of stupid for not having thought of that myself :) Thanks for the close.

Comment: Would be good if this was fixed, for mods at least, it's another speed bump when doing rapid fire flag cleanup.