# Close as "Exact Duplicate" does not recognize links from Facebook sub-domain

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions, facebook.stackoverflow

While not originally brought up as a result of [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105568/closing-duplicates-between-stackoverflow-and-facebook-stackoverflow), [balpha replied regarding this matter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105570/140951):

> We should probably make sure it works anyway...

So here's the formal feature request.

Users are able to flag a question as a duplicate of a question on the facebook sub-domain:

[image: flag history of a question on the Facebook sub-domain marked as "Exact Duplicate"]

However, when trying to use the Facebook sub-domain URL in the dialog for closing as exact duplicate, Stack Overflow doesn't recognize the URL:

[image: "duplicate question must exist on Stack Overflow]

That question looks like it exists on Stack Overflow to me.

Please fix this to allow links from the Facebook sub-domain to be accepted by the close dialog.

Currently, I have to go an manually edit the URL to take out the `facebook` sub-domain.  I've had to do this a number of times, and we get quite a few duplicate requests on Stack Overflow for Facebook sub-domain related material.

Comment: Sort of a dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105568/closing-duplicates-between-stackoverflow-and-facebook-stackoverflow - maybe turn this one into a feature-request (see balpha's answer)

Comment: @Mat Updated to make this a feature request and hopefully get balpha's butt in gear =)

Comment: This is annoying when closing it as a duplicate as well.