# Closing as duplicate on facebook.stackoverflow.com requires you to use URL to question on facebook.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close as “Exact Duplicate” does not recognize links from Facebook sub-domain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118809/close-as-exact-duplicate-does-not-recognize-links-from-facebook-sub-domain)

Bug: If you are looking at a question on facebook.stackoverflow.com and you try to close that question as a duplicate, but you use a stackoverflow.com url, the error msg states
"The duplicate question must exist on Facebook - Stack Overflow".

Expected: Either fb.stack or stack url would work
Workaround: add facebook. to the beginning of the url

[image: duplicate error msg]

Comment: Ironic duplicate is ironic.